# How to output SQLite column with quotes

Tags: csv, sqlite, export-to-csv

I have a SQLite Column that is of type VARCHAR(36). When I set the mode to CSV with `.mode csv` and execute `SELECT column_a from table_a ORDER BY column_a ASC;` I get the output as the string without double quotes. An example row would be `spotify:track:6cLgBwRc1LfV0cSoboEfJD`. I need the output to be `"spotify:track:6cLgBwRc1LfV0cSoboEfJD"`.

Answer (score 3):

String concatenation should work here, and you should be able to simply include double quotes inside a single-quoted string literal:

```
SELECT '"' || column_a || '"'
FROM table_a
ORDER BY column_a ASC;
```

Comment: For some reason, when I execute that query I get the following:

`"""spotify:track:6cLgBwRc1LfV0cSoboEfJD"""`

My statement was:

`SELECT '"' || tracks.track_uri || '"' FROM tracks INNER JOIN features ON tracks.track_uri = features.track_uri ORDER BY "key" ASC, mode DESC, tempo ASC LIMIT 100;`

Comment: Are you sure that those extra quotes were not inserted by the database?  Can you write the query output to a file and see what is there?  My guess is that it would appear normally if written to file.

Comment: The difference seems to be when using the command `.mode csv`

Comment: I'm not a SQLite expert, but I think my query should ideally work correctly.

Comment: Ok I think I've figured it out. I am using `.mode csv` so that I can import a csv file into my table. If I then also execute SELECT statement I get the 3 quotes. However when I exit out of sqlite3 and then go back in again and do the select statement I get normal quoted output.

Comment: You might want to use CSV mode, if it can handle escaping of your strings, rather than using the two query answers given here.  The tool probably knows how to handle escaping better than we do.

Comment: Further update without the query answers below, if the row contains a space the output will quoted however if it does not contain a space it will not be quoted. I wonder if that behavior can be changed?

Comment: You really need to tell us why/where you plan to use the CSV dump of your table.  The reason it is putting in quotes around fields that have spaces is that another tool (e.g. Excel, another database) can correctly figure out that those spaces are part of the data and not a field separator.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
SELECT concat(concat('"', column_a), '"') from table_a ORDER BY column_a ASC;
```